# VirtualBox cannot start a virtual machine on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, memory, virtualbox

Note that this question is mostly so others can find this information.

I ran into a problem recently with my Fedora-14 virtual machine running on a Windows-7 host with VirtualBox.

VirtualBox could not start the Fedora virtual machine, but it *could* start a Ubuntu virtual server machine that was configured for 512 MB of RAM. The Fedora-14 machine was configured for 2 GB of RAM.

The Fedora-14 machine had been working a week ago. What had I recently changed...?

Answer to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had recently changed the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters\Size` registry key to 3. I did this to stop errors happening when I transferred virtual machine images over gigabit Ethernet.

This parameter allocates more system memory to the Server service which handles serving file-sharing connections.

The `3` value is for best file-sharing service. The default value for Windows-7 is `1`. Setting this parameter to `2` instead of `3` solved my problem with VirtualBox not being able to get 2 GB of RAM for the Fedora-14 machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue generally described in the title (but varied in details). After a first install on a Windows 7 host and a successful run of Ubuntu VM, the application could not be started again. An attempt to start would show that a process is running in the task manager but no GUI appears.

Solution that worked for me: Start VirtualBox as Administrator.